# How to change website user's password using phpmyAdmin where password field is in varchar(250)?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, passwords

The website was written in php and there isn't any option to reset password for administrator. How can I change admin user's password using phpmyadmin where user's password field is in varchar(250) format?

I've found some tutorials where if I change password field to something like this:
`d9b1d7db4cd6e70935368a1efb10e377`

then i can log in to website with **123** password. But the above symbols are for varchar and my password fields require varchar250. Is there any option to convert text to varchar250 so I can just change pass field and log in to website?

How Can i change my password having access to database? What are some other ways of solving this.
Thanks

Comment: 250 is just the number of characters your varchar field can accept its not a different format. So go ahead and do it.

Comment: I tried but still can't log in

Comment: Are you sure that changing the password to what you have in the code will allow you to log in with '123' as password? If you have a varchar(250) as password field, it is unlikely that md5 is used for securing the passwords. Have you checked your code as to how the passwords are secured within your application (if secured at all)?

Comment: Probably I guess you are not storing the password in md5 format otherwise it would have surely worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

passwords Should be encrypted ... please see a code on php what encryption is being used

for example if it is using **md5** generate password online and copy and paste that hash into your database password field ..

Most probably it may use **md5** **sha1** encryption .. if you dont have any access to the code try those hash

Here is link for [md5](http://www.md5online.org/md5-encrypt.html) online encryption and [sha1](http://www.sha1-online.com/)  online encyption.
just type a password what you want to change . and copy that hash into your database admin table on password field.

Comment: How to check which encryption method is used? The script also uses bootstrap

Comment: when you enter login from database .. the method which get hit .. there will you find a code which encryption is using

Comment: could you please search for md5 or sha1 for entire folder ...?? you will find that.. if you could share a code i can help..

Comment: Passwords **should** be encrypted. Pls be more specific as to how the OP can resolve the issue because in its current form this feels more like a comment, than an answer.

Comment: md5 and sha1 are indeed common methods to secure a password, but they do not encrypt it, they hash the data. Encrypted data can be decrypted, hashed data cannot. If you have a varchar(250) field, then are you sure that md5 or sha1 is used? Both generate hashes that are a lot smaller than 250 characters.

Comment: YESSS, it was in md5. I've just replaced password field value with a new encrypted password using your link and I finallly logged into website!!!!